# Are cotton ear cleaners safe to clean the ear wax?

Tags: ear, earwax, inner-ear, cotton-swabs-q-tips, ear-canal

Wax is build in my ear and I want to clean my ear. So, I want to ask that are cotton ear cleaners safe to clean the ear wax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they just make earwax problems worse by compacting the wax and pushing it further into the ear canal.

You can buy ear drops containing carbamide peroxide that will dissolve excess wax safely. No prescription is required in the US.

[Why you shouldn't use cotton swabs to clean your ears (CNN 2017)](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/03/health/earwax-cleaning-guidelines/index.html)